# Plone: Email contents in content rule action

Tags: plone

I have a Plone site configured with PloneFormGen. I'm using a save-data-to-content adapter to create a page for each submission, with a unique number for title/id. I have content rules set up so that various roles will be notified when a submitted form transitions along the workflow.

Is there any way to include the content of the submitted in these emails? I know PloneFormGen can send the content of the form in an initial email at submit time, but I need to send this same information later. I'm pretty good at figuring things out, but I'm no Plone expert so any help would be appreciated.

Additional info:
I'm using the uwosh.pfg.d2c adapter to perform the PFG -> Contenttype conversion, which works well. The content type is set to 'page' in the settings for the uwosh.pfg.d2c plugin. Content rules then will send emails to various groups or roles based on a state transition of the resulting content, which works in the normal way - when a transition occurs, the rule executes.

Effectively, what we have is pages that are being generated by the form when the user clicks submit. This is done through a plugin in PloneFormGen. This may provide some extra info: http://pythonhosted.org/uwosh.pfg.d2c/ - I'm not, admittedly, much of a developer.

Ideally, reviewers would get body-text of the created page when the form is submitted: this is done through a content rule that when a page is added to a folder, it sends the email. The page is added to the folder when the plugin in PloneFormGen creates the page.

When we have these pages, other users can come in and review and change the state of them - just as you can with any other page in Plone. PloneFormGen should have no further use once it's been converted to a page. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The bad news is that this will require programming; the good news is that it won't take much. There are two reasonable approaches to solving the problem:

1. Have your content rule action run a script that handles the mailing itself. You can use the site's mailhost to send scripted mail; or,
2. In a Python package (no way to do this in a through-the-web script), provide a named adapter implementing plone.stringinterp.interfaces.IStringSubstitution for your context's text attribute. That will give you a $ substitution for the body. This would probably require less than 10 lines of total code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems like the first solution might be the easier one for me. Is there any documentation available how to proceed down that route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look a collective.contentrules.mailtogroup, the newest version is capable to send the body-text as mail (use the '${text}'-variable), triggered on one of the convenient content-rules-events, in your case 'Object added'.

You can assign your roles to a group and use it for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually have the collective.contentrules.mailtogroup installed, as well as the collective.contentrules.mailtorole add-on. I love the functionality of these, but I can't find a way to include the text of the object in question (whatever object is triggering the rule) in the text of the email. If that can be done - then that would make my life even easier!

Comment: I tried using the ${text} variable, and it seems to be trying to work, but I get the following error and traceback:

http://pastebin.com/sJ28QsW9

Comment: It assumes, the contenttype has a field with the name 'text', is that the case?

Comment: For the record: Just released c.c.mailtogroup-1.3.1 with a bugfix, considering the text-variable is used, but the item doesn't have that field.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I set one of the PloneFormGen fields to be called 'text', but that did not correct the situation. After updating the plugin to version 1.3.1, I now get the following error - even without using variables in the body:

http://pastebin.com/Rd2xPEds

Comment: c.c.mailtogroup works on contenttype's events, not on pfg-records. I am not familiar with the mechanism of the pfg-to-ct-transform (are you using the uwosh-product by any chance? Please update your quest about how you transform). I assumed, you can apply the contentrule on the created ct. Which trigger do you actually want, a state-transition? Please update your quest with more info about that.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide more info - please let me know what else I can provide. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still don't get: a) when the transition is triggered (on submitting the form/on creation of the ct), which interface is the event-handler listening to? b) what is triggering the transition (user-action/pfg-script after form-submit)? Or in other words, what's the usecase? (f.e.: 'if a form is submitted, a reviewer should get a mail with bodytext of the form')

Comment: I, admittedly, don't know the answer to A. More info above.

Comment: When the automatically generated form page changes workflow state, send the email with the body-text to group 'X'...that's basically what it boils down to.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, is the workflow-state changed on an user-action (user changes state manually) or otherwise? But I am afraid, I can't help much more, unless getting famililar with the uwosh-product. Do you know a good usage-doc for it, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, the user will change the state manually. The uwosh product seems fairly simple to use, though I recognize that figuring out what it's doing in the background may not be so. Here's what information I have been able to find on its operation:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uwosh.pfg.d2c

http://pythonhosted.org/uwosh.pfg.d2c/

Comment: Is this outside the scope of the plugin?

Comment: Tested the uwosh-proudct, you can use the title-variable in a mail but no other fields, seems they are handled in a different way than the usual contenttype-fields :( Yet, now I noticed an interesting product: collective.pfg.dexterity. It claims to convert pfg-forms to dexterity-ct's. This approach might be unnecessarily complex and SteveM's second proposal could be faster, even if it requires more programing skills. HTH.